# google search the file name true a script in the context menu?

Tags: search, contextmenu, right-click

First of all sorry for my bad English.

Is there a way to search google for the file name.
so a right click menu script that runs google and searches for the file name

the main questions are

- is it possible?
- which coding language to use?
- does it already exist or do i need to make it myself (with help)?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean filename is a title of a webpage? If so you can use `allintitle:` keyword:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=allintitle:stackoverflow
```

will search for any page contains `stackoverflow` in the title.
Or to search within a URL, use`allinurl:` keyword:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=allinurl:stackoverflow
```

will search for any page contains `stackoverflow` in the URL.
To search for specific type of file, use`filetype:` keyword:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+filetype:pdf
```

will search for any page contains a PDF document about `stackoverflow`.
If that is what you mean, then it is possible, and you can use almost any programing language you like.